# error: MySQl server hase gane away

Tags: php, yii2

Устроился на работу, и там весь код через **** написан и не одного комментария, второй день мучаюсь....
До этого в кроне висела задача запускаемая через wget
Я метод контроллера перенес в консоль и запускаю php yii ...
Выбивает ошибку : 
error: MySQl server hase gane away 
Контроллер:

```
public function actionSetidclientforrequest(){
    $model=new Clients();
    return $model->setIdClientForRequest();

}
```

Модель:

```
public function setIdClientForRequest(){
    $connection = Yii::$app->db;
    $errors = array();
    try{


    $requests=$connection->createCommand("SELECT id_orders_register,vk,fio FROM orders_register WHERE id_client=0 OR id_client IS NULL")->queryAll();
    foreach ($requests as $key=>$request){

        $vkId=$this->getVkId($request['vk']);
        $idClient=$connection->createCommand("SELECT id_client FROM clients WHERE uid=:uid")
            ->bindValue(":uid",$vkId['uid'])
            ->queryScalar();
        if($idClient){
            $connection->createCommand()->update("orders_register",['id_client'=>$idClient],['id_orders_register'=>$request['id_orders_register']])->execute();
        }
    }
    } catch (Exception $e){
        array_push($errors, $e->getMessage());
    }
    return var_dump($errors);
}
```

Подскажите, куда копать? php 5.4

Comment: [это](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html) вы уже прочитали?

Comment: распространенной причиной получения ошибки MySQL server has gone away является выдача команды "закрытия" на соединении MySQL с последующей попыткой выполнить запрос на закрытом соединении. http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Gone_away.html

Comment: Самое интересное на локалке если ставлю конфигурацию php7 то без ошибок все отрабатывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите что выводит

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%timeout%"
```

И попробуйте добавить в начале скрипта

```
$connection->createCommand('SET SESSION wait_timeout = 3600;')->execute();
$connection->createCommand('SET SESSION interactive_timeout = 3600;')->execute();
```

И, если вы говорите, что при смене версии php меняется поведение, сравните старый и новый конфиги php, например mysql.connect_timeout

Comment: В конфиге таймаут был выставлен в 5 секунд